# UPDATE only when CASE matches?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update, case

I would like to update a few field values to new ones and leave the rest alone:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET fieldname = CASE fieldname
                     WHEN 'foo' THEN 'bar'
                     WHEN 'baz' THEN 'bam'
                     ELSE fieldname END
```

Is there a way to do this without the `ELSE fieldname` part? To tell UPDATE to only match the row if there's a match? The CASE is long, I'd rather not repeat the left side of all cases in a `WHERE`.

Comment: `WHERE fieldname IN ('foo','baz')` ?  And then you can leave out the `ELSE fieldname`, because that would never be a match anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to avoid repeating the list of values twice in the `CASE` expression and the `WHERE` clause, then you can use a CTE that returns the list and join it to the table:

```
WITH cte(current_value, new_value) AS (VALUES ROW('foo', 'bar'), ROW('baz', 'bam'))
UPDATE tablename t
JOIN cte c ON c.current_value = t.fieldname
SET t.fieldname = c.new_value;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ejvoo_Hk).

For versions of MySql prior to 8.0 without support of CTEs and the `VALUES ROW()` table value constructor:

```
UPDATE tablename t
JOIN (
  SELECT 'foo' current_value, 'bar' new_value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'baz', 'bam'
) c ON c.current_value = t.fieldname
SET t.fieldname = c.new_value;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/n9oIjbJk).